# Displaying visual content on a building with ARKit

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, ios12

We want to display content on a building in real life. The building is very big, I think we will have troubles with using ARKit to [scan and detect objects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects). What should we use to scan a building and/or display visual content (like red dots you can touch to get more info about the single components of the building)?

We also thought about image tracking. Any hints on which technology is the most appropriate for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very complicated question. I think if you are near the building you can apply an [image recognition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience) technique for any plate with logo on a wall (or for any distinctive part of the facade) employing `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()` or `ARImageTrackingConfiguration()` classes.

But if you're far from the building you can apply object detection technique employing `ARReferenceObject()` and `ARObjectScanningConfiguration()` classes respectively. So there would be a kind of symbiosis of different techniques in your AR application.

Hope this helps.